# Connecting a controller to your application fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am creating an application that requires the user to set a password. My password scene is written in fxml. After the user clicks the register button I would like the controller to notify the main application and give it the password so it can use it Currently I am doing that by subclassing the controller like so

```
    class RegisterClass
{
    private Stage stage = new Stage();
    private Scene scene;
    @FXML PasswordField secondpass;
    @FXML PasswordField firstpass;
    @FXML Label error;
    @FXML Button register;
    public RegisterClass()
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/quagrum/resources/fxml/register.fxml"));
        Pane par = null;


        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
         try {
                par = fxmlLoader.load();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exception);
            }
         scene= new Scene(par,219,240);
         stage.setScene(scene);
         stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResource("/com/quagrum/resources/images/NewQuagrumIco.png").toString()));
            scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent ke)
                {
                    if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
                    {
                        register.fire();
                    }
                }
            });
            stage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
                System.exit(0);
            });
            stage.showAndWait();
    }
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        register.setOnAction(e->{

            if(firstpass.getText().equals(secondpass.getText()))
            {
                if(firstpass.getText().length()==0)
                {
                    password=firstpass.getText();
                    createLock();
                    stage.close();
                }else
                {
                    password=firstpass.getText();
                    createLock();
                    stage.close();
                }

            }else
            {
                error.setText("Passwords do not match");
                error.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
private void register()//this one setups all the accounts with the new password
{
    RegisterClass register = new RegisterClass();
}
```

However, this makes my code in the parent class much longer as I have also done the same thing with the login page. So my question is, is there a way I can create a seperate controller class that will interact with the caller and send the passwords or is this currently the best way.

Comment: this code looks quite wrong (because of blocking in the constructor). implement `Supplier<T>` in the controller (which you use to return the entered password) or better - use `Dialog<R>`

Comment: Sorry I don't know what blocking in the constructor means. And could you explain how to use a supplier

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry I don't know what blocking in the constructor means.

This is the call to `stage.showAndWait();` in the `RegisterClass` constructor. This is a very bad design in terms of OOP.

There are different mechanisms through which you can get data from this controller. The simplest thing is to make a geter to return the new password. The implementation of `Supplier<T>` does exactly that (use of the interface is not mandatory but will later help you communicate more easily with the other components in the system without violating the OOP principles)

```
public class RegisterClass implements Supplier<Optional<String>> {

    ...

    public Optional<String> showAndWait() {
        stage.showAndWait();
        return get();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<String> get() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(password);
    }
}
```

Accordingly, the call a bit differs, but you already have a mechanism to get your new password

```
RegisterClass register = new RegisterClass();
register.showAndWait().ifPresent(password -> {
    System.out.println("New password: " + password);
});
```

Another option is to use `Consumer<T>` to register with `RegisterClass` to get the new password

```
public class RegisterClass {
    private Consumer<Optional<String>> passwordHandler;

    ...

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        register.setOnAction(e->{
            if(firstpass.getText().equals(secondpass.getText()))
            {
                if(firstpass.getText().length()==0)
                {
                    password=firstpass.getText();
                    createLock();
                    stage.close();
                }else
                {
                    password=firstpass.getText();
                    createLock();
                    stage.close();
                }

                if(passwordHandler != null) {
                    passwordHandler.accept(Optional.ofNullable(password));
                }

            }else
            {
                error.setText("Passwords do not match");
                error.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    ...

    public void addPasswordHandler(Consumer<Optional<String>> passwordHandler) {
        this.passwordHandler = passwordHandler;
    }

    public void showAndWait() {
        stage.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

In this case, the use is a bit more complicated because you have to create a `Consumer<T>` instance and submit it to `RegisterClass`

```
public class MainController {
    private Consumer<Optional<String>> passwordHandler = password -> {
        System.out.println(password);
    };

    @FXML
    private void handleRegister(ActionEvent event) {
        RegisterClass register = new RegisterClass();
        register.addPasswordHandler(passwordHandler);
        register.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

The latter example can be expanded using `Singleton` to avoid manual registration of `Consumer<T>`. This is good to do if you have a lot of invoked controller calls and do not want to complicate the logic by passing parameters between them.

```
public class RegisterClass {
    ...

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        register.setOnAction(e->{
            if(firstpass.getText().equals(secondpass.getText()))
            {
                if(firstpass.getText().length()==0)
                {
                    password=firstpass.getText();
                    createLock();
                    stage.close();
                }else
                {
                    password=firstpass.getText();
                    createLock();
                    stage.close();
                }

                Consumer<Optional<String>> passwordHandler = MainController.getPasswordHandler();
                if(passwordHandler != null) {
                    passwordHandler.accept(Optional.ofNullable(password));
                }

            }else
            {
                error.setText("Passwords do not match");
                error.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    ...
    public void showAndWait() {
        stage.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

This is the use

```
public class MainController {
    private static Consumer<Optional<String>> passwordHandler;

    public static Consumer<Optional<String>> getPasswordHandler() {
        return passwordHandler;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        passwordHandler = password -> {
            System.out.println(password);
        };
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleRegister(ActionEvent event) {
        RegisterClass register = new RegisterClass();
        register.showAndWait();
    }
}
```